# Unable to load DLL 'OraOps.dll' al correr Business Process Deployer - WorkFlow GeneXus 17

Tags: genexus

Cordial saludo

Me encuentro haciendo un deploy de una aplicación desarrollada con GeneXus 17 Upgrade 10, la cual cuenta con WorkFlow. Usa el generador C# .Net Framework y se conecta a una base de datos Oracle 12c.

Procedí a crear el archivo con extensión BPD desde el IDE de GeneXus, y lo llevé a un servidor de producción, en el cual instalé una herramienta de GeneXus llamada "GeneXus Flow Production Environment 17 Upgrade 10" (la cual es una aplicación de 32 bits).

Al ejecutar este programa para hacer despliegue de WorkFlow y actualizar la estructura de las tablas de WorkFlow (las cuales necesitan actualización porque se encuentran impactadas desde el 2018), aparece un error en la primera fase del deploy, que informa lo siguiente:

> Unable to load DLL 'OraOps.dll'

Por esta razón, esa aplicación no puede conectarse a la base de datos.

En el servidor de producción se encuentran varios clientes de Oracle instalados, en total 3. En ese mismo servidor se logró correr el GAM Deploy Tool de GeneXus 17 U10 (que es una aplicación de 32 bits), y se conectó de forma correcta a la base de datos Oracle, lo cual me hace pensar que las configuraciones de los clientes de Oracle si permiten en ese servidor que aplicaciones de  32 bits se conecten de forma exitosa a la base de datos.

Se copió al directorio donde se está haciendo la ejecución del programa, varias DLLs, entre las que están:

- oci.dll
- Oracle.DataAccess.dll
- oraociei12.dll
- OraOps12.dll

Se ha intentado empaquetar manualmente el archivo BPD, con esas librerías, cambiando la extensión del archivo a zip, descomprimiendo los archivos, incluyendo las librerías y volviendo a comprimir a zip y finalmente dejando la extensión .bpd, ya que se logró entender que este archivo no es más que un comprimido ZIP con la extensión cambiada a bpd.

¿Hay algo que se pueda hacer para entender qué hace falta para que corra bien esa aplicación, y en qué directorio se requiere colocar?
Gracias de antemano por su atención.